# Publish PIP Package, Need to set PYTHONPATH explicitly?

Tags: python, pip

I am attempting to publish my first PIP package and I have some concern here.

This is the structure of my package. Let's call my package fox.

```
project-folder
    fox
        exceptions.py
        ...
        user.py
    setup.py
    readme.md
    LICENSE
```

When building this package, I took the liberty to explicitly set `PYTHONPATH` in my shell so I would be able to import my package like

```
import fox
fox.user() # do something
```

I noticed when publishing PIP package we do not have to specify how to set PYTHONPATH.

My question is, do we need to, in somewhere write a script and explicitly, specify the `export PYTHONPATH` statement so that the users would import the package the same way?

Or does PIP implicitly do that for us already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect your users to use a POSIX-compatible shell; and your package should not mess with the user's environment, anyway. Setting your user's `PYTHONPATH` is not at all the right approach here.

Instead, what you (optionally) do is put a default `import` statement in your module's `__init__.py`

```
import user, exceptions
```

Comment: Yes I did that already, so the package manager will automatically manage the dependencies for me? As in I shouldn't worry about this statement `import fox` afterwards.

Comment: @Rex. Since that's literally the whole point of the package manager, we hope that it will do that. Your package will end up probably in the user's site-packages folder, which is very much in the path already. As long as your code is importable, don't worry about the rest.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the clarification. I will try to publish soon!